# Websockets and external API

Tags: html, api, websocket

If I had a website that currently utilizes a PHP [Basecamp API](http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/) to request data from a basecamp account and serve it to my client-side application how would the introduction of HTML5's websockets benefit this? Or maybe it doesn't at all.

My understanding would be that this process allows for bi-directional socket connection allowing for real-time updates and notifications. ie.a user edits a comment via my client-side app and a user on basecamp would see that change in real-time. Is this correct or am I'm barking up the wrong tree?
Correct me if I'm wrong but would Basecamp require something along the line of Node.js to open this two-way connection?

Here's a sample chat app using similar techniques:

http://www.martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial

Cheers

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue of whether it's better to use ajax to pull data or web sockets. It seems to me that if you're constantly pinging for data that web sockets would be a better solution but if you're just filling user requests with real time data then ajax might be a better solution. Hopefully someone comes along and gives a better answer though.

Comment: Any idea on how to accomplish this? Does Basecamp allow for realtime requests?